# Celery - task succedes before it's subtasks

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, celery-task

I can't figure out why my task is considered to be done before all its subtasks are done.

```
tasks.scan_user.delay(1)
```

CODE:

```
@task()
def scan_chunk(ids):
    occs = Occurence.objects.filter(product_id__in=ids)
    result = scan_occurences_dummy_pool((x.id,x.url,x.xpath) for x in occs)
    return result

@task()
def scan_user(id): 
    chunks = generate_chunks_from_user(id)
    ch = chain(scan_chunk.si([x.id for x in chunk]) for chunk in chunks)
    return ch()
```

This is the Celery output, as you can see, the `scan_user` succeeded before all `scan_chunks` are done which is a problem because I want `scan_user` to us in another `chain`.

```
[2017-02-09 14:27:03,493: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: engineapp.tasks.scan_user[ed358a98-a685-4002-baac-993fdc7b64cf]
[2017-02-09 14:27:05,721: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: engineapp.tasks.scan_chunk[35b74e01-f9fa-471f-8c20-ecbf99a89201]
[2017-02-09 14:27:06,740: INFO/MainProcess] Task engineapp.tasks.scan_user[ed358a98-a685-4002-baac-993fdc7b64cf] succeeded in 3.24300003052s: <AsyncResult: 442f9373-d983-4696-a42a-ba42a8ce7761>
[2017-02-09 14:27:22,178: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: engineapp.tasks.scan_chunk[36a94ad4-3c9e-4f7d-a040-5c2a617a0d8f]
[2017-02-09 14:27:23,204: INFO/MainProcess] Task engineapp.tasks.scan_chunk[35b74e01-f9fa-471f-8c20-ecbf99a89201] succeeded in 17.4779999256s: [
```

I would like to create another `task` which will run sequentially `scan_user` for all users, but I think this is not possible since it would be in fact parallel.

Answer (score 1):

`ch()` just runs the chain without waiting for the result.
If you want to wait, do:

```
ch = chain(scan_chunk.si([x.id for x in chunk]) for chunk in chunks)()
return ch.get()
```